# Best way to create a sequence with 1 item

Tags: f#, sequence

In F# I can create a sequence of 1 item by

```
seq [42]          // inefficient, since a list is created
seq { yield 42}   // verbose, would prefer { 42 } or seq { 42 }
seq { 42 .. 42 }  // bizarre
```

While I find this a bit strange, I am curious if someone knows a short and efficient way.
Or: Why is

```
{ 42 }  // invalid syntax. in other words, not a valid sequence expression
```

not valid?

Comment: [42] is shorter than seq [42] but still creates an unnecessary list.

Comment: Well, `seq { yield 42 }` still creates an `IEnumerable` instance and has a few hidden method invocations. If efficiency is an issue for you, I would recommend against using `seq` expressions in general.

Comment: certainly it does. you might understand that I do not always create singletons, so lets stick with the very simple question as it stands. actually [x] is the nicest looking alternative and i considered using it regardless of the added list creation. but doing so, type inference gets stuck and requires type annotations on the other hand, not so nice either. so finally settled for Seq.singleton as the idiomatic coding style.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use:

```
Seq.singleton 42
```

Comment: obviously this is the f# intended way. while { 42 } would be more conceise, singleton is verbose but expressive.

Answer (score 7):

If you need a true sequence (i.e. an `IEnumerable` whose items are created lazily), the `seq { yield <expr> }` is probably the most concise syntax.

If you don't need the item to be evaluated only when it is consumed (eager evaluation is fine), then you can use the `Seq.singleton` function.

If you only need something that implements `IEnumerable`, you can achieve shorter syntax by using a list or an array constructor: `[ <expr> ]` or `[| <expr> |]`, the difference being that array constructor will be probably more efficient in this case.

The `{ <expr> }` syntax won't work because there is no such special syntax for creating a sequence (as, for example, a [generator expression](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) in Python). The `seq { yield <stuff> }` is a [computation expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx), and it has to follow several rules, one of which being that it has to say what kind of computation it defines (the `seq` part says that). If you wanted to omit the `seq` part, you'd need F# to support generic computation expressions, which I don't think is currently possible (and would probably require some capability similar to typeclasses).